# Replacing LDAP store in Axiomatics to use Azure AD / B2C

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac

We have some applications that currently use Axiomatics for fine grain authorization and it uses the LDAP connector to check for user attributes / group membership. We are exploring the migration of on premise LDAP users to Azure AD B2C, however currently Axiomatics policy enforcement connects to this LDAP. Is it possible for Axiomatics to use Azure AD API instead of LDAP ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I believe there is an HTTP connector you can use to talk to rest services. You can combine it with the JSON parser to Parse the response from azure AD.